# How to extract individual values from Firestore getDocument request using Swift

Tags: swift, firebase

```
let db = Firestore.firestore()
let docRef = db.collection("users").document(result!.user.uid)

docRef.getDocument { (document, error) in
    if let document = document, document.exists {
        let dataDescription = document.data().map(String.init(describing:)) ?? "nil"
        print("Document data: \(dataDescription)")
        print()
        
    } else {
        print("Document does not exist")
    }
}
```

`print("Document data: \(dataDescription)")` outputs the following:

Document data: `["uid": LjqBXo41qMStt89ysQ4I9hxla2h1, "firstname": Tim, "lastname": Dorsemagen]`

How can I extract each value such as the `uid`, the `firstname` and the `lastname` from `dataDescription`?

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to accomplish this.  One of the most easily understood would be to break the string down in sections.  Assuming you only want the values rather than their keys:

```
let values  = dataDescription
   .dropFirst()
   .dropLast()
   .components(separatedBy: ",")
   .map{$0.components(separatedBy: ":")}
   .map{$0.last!.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces)}

print(values) //["LjqBXo41qMStt89ysQ4I9hxla2h1", "Tim", "Dorsemagen"]
```

Comment: Thank you! This works assuming the relative position of the values is known and does not change. Is there a method to reliably extract the individual values based on the keys in case the position does change?

Comment: @DavidWetzel While this answer works, Firestore SDK has everything needed to extract data from Firebase snapshots.  This is not a bad answer by any means, but it's not really Firebasey. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Firestore has everything needed to easily get components of a document. Here's an asynchronous example of reading a users name from a document and returning it

```
func getUserAsync() async -> String{
    let usersCollection = self.db.collection("users") //self.db is my Firestore
    let thisUserDoc = usersCollection.document("uid_0")
    let document = try! await thisUserDoc.getDocument()
    
    let name = document.get("name") as? String ?? "No Name"
    
    return name
}
```

if you want to use Codable (advised! See [Mapping Firestore Data](https://peterfriese.dev/posts/firestore-codable-the-comprehensive-guide/)), this works for printing the name (can also be combined with the above solution)

```
func readUser() {
    let usersCollection = self.db.collection("users") //self.db is my Firestore
    let thisUserDoc = usersCollection.document("uid_0")

    thisUserDoc.getDocument(completion: { document, error in
        if let doc = document {
            let user = try! doc.data(as: UserCodable.self)
            print(user.name) //assume the UserCodable object has a name property
        }
    }
}
```

or just a regular old read of a document and print the name

```
func readUser() {
    let usersCollection = self.db.collection("users") //self.db is my Firestore
    let thisUserDoc = usersCollection.document("uid_0")

    thisUserDoc.getDocument(completion: { document, error in
        let name = document?.get("name") as? String ?? "No Name"
        print(name)
    })
}
```

*note: no error checking and I am force unwrapping options. Don't do that.